# How to use cross-validation and early stopping together?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cross-validation

I have to train my model using K-fold cross validation but at the same time I want to use Early stopping to prevent overfitting. How can it be done ? Since Early stopping will return a different model in each fold, does the average of the accuracies of the folds mean anything ?

Comment: Not recommended; see own answer in [Early stopping with Keras and sklearn GridSearchCV cross-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127550/early-stopping-with-keras-and-sklearn-gridsearchcv-cross-validation/48139341#48139341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when you do not use Early Stopping, every time you use Cross-Validation you have a different model in each fold: the model has different parameters and different results, but that's the point of CV. You can use ES without any particular attention.